# RabbitMQ queue size without Spring? (java api)

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm using the Java client with RabbitMQ.  I've seen references to finding queue size with a Spring plugin, but I'm not using Spring.  Is there a non-Spring way to get the size of a queue given its name?  Right now I'm just exec'ing shell commands 'rabbitmqctl list_queues' and parsing the results--not great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enable the [http management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html),

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

then use the [http API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_4_3/priv/www/api/index.html).

If you execute an http call like:

```
http://your_server/api/queues/your_virtual_host/yourqueue
```

you have all information about the queue, the output is a json like:

```
  ... "backing_queue_status": {
    "q1": 0,
    "q2": 0,
    "delta": [
      "delta",
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "q3": 0,
    "q4": 0,
    "len": 0,
    "target_ram_count": 0,
    "next_seq_id": 0,
    "avg_ingress_rate": 0,
    "avg_egress_rate": 0,
    "avg_ack_ingress_rate": 0,
    "avg_ack_egress_rate": 0,
    "mirror_seen": 0,
    "mirror_senders": 0
  },
  "incoming": [],
  "deliveries": [],
  "consumer_details": [],
  "name": "myqueue",
  "vhost": "vhost",
  "durable": true,
  "auto_delete": false,
  "arguments": {},
  "node": "rabbit@lemur01"
}
```